# How do I use Less with Express.js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, less

I'm trying to use Less with Express.js however I'm not sure my setup is the correct one.

My folder/files structure is the following :

- ....
- app.js
- public

  - styles

    - test.less
- ........

And in my `app.js` :

```
var express = require('./node_modules/express');
var lessMiddleware = require('./node_modules/less-middleware');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.set("views", "./views");

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) 
{
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname + "/public/styles"));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000);
```

In my `index.ejs` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/styles/test.css">
```

If I understand correctly, the module is supposed to take my `test.less` and compile it into `test.css` before it serves it to the client ?

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE :** it looks like nothing is being served from /public..

`http://localhost:3000/public` returns `Cannot GET /public`

Comment: How do you serve stati files?

Comment: Any errors in console? What is response for any css file from browser? Why do you require with ./node_modules? You could use `require('less-middleware')`

Comment: I'm installing node modules locally - nothing to do with issue I'm having. I'm getting not server-side errors. I get a `404 test.css not found` on the client.

Comment: I think href should be `styles/test.css` without `public` prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have /public/less instead of /public/styles, and you need to serve that directory as a static one:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Then make your link href /styles/test.css.

EDIT:

You need to move your less middleware and static middleware to the top before any routes you define.

Comment: I did that and `test.less` is still not being compiled

Comment: You need to put your less middleware and static middleware before your route. They aren't being run.

Answer (score -1):

I mean you need install this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-less

Comment: why ? I'm using `less-middleware`

Answer (score -1):

Simply install less middleware by running `npm install --save less-middleware` and add this line to your app.js file:

`app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

It'll check all the `.less` files and compile them on the fly.

Comment: As you can see in my OP, the module has already been installed

Comment: Then the problem is how you are importing it. Just use `require('less-middleware')` not the whole path. That's why I added this example but what I have is a minus one.